# Return Eloquent model with different name from database tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to return a JSON of an Eloquent model, but I'd like to change the array keys. By default they are set as the table field names, but I want to change them.

For example if I have a users table with two fields : id and user_name

When I return User::all(); I'll have a JSON with "[{"id" => 1, "user_name" => "bob}] etc.

I'd like to be able to change user_name to username. I haven't found the way to do it without an ugly foreach loop on the model.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not just keep the names uniform throughout your app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this in the first place and would warn you first about the structure if your app/would it be better to make things uniform throughout.. but if you **really** want to do it.. you could do:

```
$user = User::find($id);
return Response::json(array('id' => $user->id, 'username' => $user->user_name));
```

That will return a JSON object with what you want.

You can also change the name of the key with:

```
$arr[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey];
unset($arr[$oldkey]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at robclancy's `presenter` package, this `ServiceProvider` handles those things you want to achieve.

[GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/robclancy/presenter)

Answer (score -1):

Just set the $hidden static for you model to the keys you want to hide:

class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $hidden = 'id';

}

and name them the way you like with get and set functons.